# Open a web url as an Excel file from inside Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel file on a website that gets updated regularly.

www.mysite.com/Update.xlsx

Is there a way to create a shortcut, or from within Excel to open this link as an Excel document?

I must be missing something really simple!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help. I got it solved using a combination of ideas.

I made a shortcut, and used the /e parameter like so:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2010\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /e "http://www.mysite.com/Update.xlsx"

Works perfectly :-)

I can't mark anything as answer, as due to associating my account with OpenId, I seem to have lost ownership of this question.

Knox if I have a link then it opens IE, prompts for Open or Save etc, which I don't really want to expose the user to.

Thanks all!

Comment: It works for me, but you might change the path of the excel executable file.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do figure out how to get Excel to open a file from a URL, you realize it will not be editable right? Perhaps you should look into some sort of file sharing system such as [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) or Microsoft's Sharepoint or [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com)?

Answer (score 0):

In file name text field type http://www.example.com/Update.xlsx and click Open.. :-)

n.b. in this approach, the URL is subject to 256 character limit, which is incredibly unfortunate. that goes for the VBA subroutine "Workbooks.Open" as well.

Comment: Is there a way to make a shortcut for that? I am aiming for a shortcut that everytime they click it, it just opens the link in Excel. (So it is always the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl K and it brings up the Insert Hyperlink dialog. You can specify the text for the link and where it goes to (www.mysite.com/Update.xlsx).

Comment: This just adds an url to the sheet in the current sheet

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows desktop, you could always make a shortcut.  Right mouse click and select "New Shortcut".  Then put the URL including http:\.  If you wanted, this shortcut could be put into the start menu or a quick launch bar.